# How to import and run these files on ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: php, android, sql

I have the below files in a folder. I cannot find how to open and run it on Android Studio. Is there any proper way of importing these files? Should I create a new project, or can I just double click on a file and run it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxfwA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to File
2. Click Open
3. Navigate to your target folder
4. Select "build.gradle"
5. Click on Ok button

Comment: It shows a loading bar saying, "Building 'LoginAndRegisterUser' Gradle project info.", but this never opens. What should I do?

Comment: Depends on System Configurations and internet speed. Let it say as it is for a while.

Comment: Problem solved. There were some tools to import. About after half an hour it showed the link to download and install the tools.

Comment: Great.. Welcome to Android Studio ;)

Answer (score 0):

File ---> Open --->{Select the folder containing these files}-->OK

that's it
Suppose all these files are under "NewApp" folder then select 'NewApp' folder and open

Answer (score 0):

1.click on file.
2.click on open.
3.select the target folder which containing these file.
(if not showing then refresh that window on lick of refresh icon)
4.ok.(build is running)